# How can I Get the most recent "Effective-date" that is less than or equal to the current date

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, rdbms, openedge, progress-db

Using Crystal Reports 2016, Progress Openedge 11.7 ODBC driver for DB connector

I have been working with the "Add Command" function in crystal reports 2016, and the SQL Query I have created so far has gotten me the closest to my desired results, but I need to figure out how to return the first row of each list price sequence, grouped by "Product key then Location Key then List price sequence". I have tried the "Row_Number()" option, but it does not exist within the Progress OpenEdge DB (not a recognized command)

```
Select "product-key", "location-key", "list-price-sequence", "effective-date", "price", "system-id"
FROM "APPRISE"."PUB"."product-price" p
WHERE  (p."location-key"='00000001' OR p."location-key"='00000008') AND 
(p."list-price-sequence" = '1' OR p."list-price-sequence" = '3') AND
p."effective-date"<= curdate() AND 
p."system-id"='Aamerica'
GROUP BY p."product-key", p."location-key", p."list-price-sequence", p."effective-date", p."price", p."system-id"
ORDER BY p."location-key" ASC, p."list-price-sequence" ASC, p."effective-date" DESC
```

The Product Price table in the DB stores a list of prices. That I have grouped by |
Product Key |
Location Key |
List Price Sequence

and then ordered by Effective date descending

I am including an image. the items highlighted in Yellow are the current records needed. The non-highlighted items are old prices and need to be discarded through the SQL query above.

[Table result of the above SQL query Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPZ92.png)

Comment: It's not clear what date you want per SKU. Most recent non-future? Returning rows with the max or min of some column per group is a faq. It even has a tag: [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. Please don't ask duplicate questions. But you can't find an existing Q&A if you don't clearly concisely completely generically phrase what you want. (Like I just did). But if you have code that doesn't do what you expect then put your search for that query on hold & post a separate (specific researched non-duplicate) question re why that code doesn't work. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please avoid hello, thanks, etc. Please don't insert EDITs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. (Last edited time is under a post & clicking it gives its edit history.) Please don't put things only in the title.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why

Answer (score 0):

Using `row_number` this should work for most RDBMS implementations

```
select sku, price from (
    select *, Row_Number() over (partition by sku order by EffectiveDate desc) rn
    from t
    where EffectiveDate < [ GetDate() / CURRDATE() / CURR_DATE() etc] depending on DB
)t
where t.rn=1
```

Comment: Stu, I just wanted to update. I haven't had a chance to test your suggestion yet. I will let you know if this works..

Comment: Stu, I am not sure if its an issue with the type of DB, but I am getting a syntax error in SQL statement at or about *, Row_Number() over (partition by "product-key" order by "effective-date" desc) rn (10713) [Database Vendor Code: -210056]

Comment: Stu, The best I can tell so far, the ROW_NUMBER() is not available within my SQL options. The Database that my ERP is using is OpenEdge Progress (Type 2). I have tried several variations of the syntaxand nothing seems to work. if there is anything else you can think of please let me know.